# Tips on Increasing Performance and Decreasing Boot Time - Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: startup

I finished installing Ubuntu 21.04. I chose this over 20.04 LTS because it doesn't support my wifi adapter natively. I have hopped around different distros trying to find the one with the quickest boot time. So far, Xubuntu 21.04 is the fastest starting up, but is buggy and I don't like Xfce. I am trying to decrease my boot time, not for pickiness or 'flexing,' but because I run an online business,  and every minute counts. In case this helps,
here are my computer specs:

- 2TB 5400 rpm SATA
- 12GB DDR4-2400 SDRAM
- 802.11b/g/n/ac Wifi and Bluetooth 4.2 Combo (Realtek RTL8821ce)
- Ubuntu 21.04 dual booted with Windows 10
- AMD Athlon Gold 3150U (2.4GHz, up to 3.3 Ghz, 1 MB L2 cache, 2 cores) with AMD Radeon Graphics

Output from `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
1min 27.453s snapd.seeded.service
1min 17.267s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     16.950s networkd-dispatcher.service
     14.426s snapd.service
     10.870s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     10.163s dev-sda6.device
      8.543s udisks2.service
      7.301s apparmor.service
      6.341s NetworkManager.service
      6.310s ModemManager.service
      6.216s accounts-daemon.service
      4.649s polkit.service
      4.227s thermald.service
      3.986s bluetooth.service
      3.986s avahi-daemon.service
      3.898s wpa_supplicant.service
      3.878s power-profiles-daemon.service
      3.734s apport.service
      3.699s switcheroo-control.service
      3.689s systemd-logind.service
      3.435s cups.service
      3.431s e2scrub_reap.service
      3.323s dev-loop2.device
```

Output from `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
graphical.target @2min 8.160s
└─multi-user.target @2min 8.160s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @40.705s +1min 27.453s
    └─snapd.service @26.271s +14.426s
      └─basic.target @25.806s
        └─sockets.target @25.805s
          └─snapd.socket @25.804s +1ms
            └─sysinit.target @25.558s
              └─snapd.apparmor.service @22.981s +2.577s
                └─apparmor.service @15.678s +7.301s
                  └─local-fs.target @15.676s
                    └─run-snapd-ns-snap\x2dstore.mnt.mount @1min 7.986s
                      └─run-snapd-ns.mount @1min 6.169s
                        └─local-fs-pre.target @6.251s
                          └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @6.201s +50ms
                            └─systemd-sysusers.service @4.618s +1.581s
                              └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.243s +289ms
                                └─systemd-journald.socket @4.071s
                                  └─-.mount @4.063s
                                    └─-.slice @4.063s
```

Output from `systemd-analyze`:

```
Startup finished in 5.921s (firmware) + 6.908s (loader) + 7.139s (kernel) + 2min 8.173s (userspace) = 2min 28.143s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 8.160s in userspace
```

For @heynnema:

Output of `snap list`:

```
Name                Version             Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
core18              20210309            1997   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core20              20210319            975    latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-34-1804     0+git.3556cb3       66     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes   0.1-52-gb92ac40     1515   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snap-store          3.38.0-59-g494f078  518    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd               2.50                11841  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
whitesur-gtk-theme  3.4                 74     latest/stable    spider623   -
```

Output of `free -h`:

```
 total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          9.7Gi       1.8Gi       785Mi        70Mi       7.1Gi       7.5Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       1.0Mi       2.0Gi
```

Output of `sysctl vm.swappiness`:

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C memory`:

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: AMI
       physical id: 0
       version: F.57
       date: 09/28/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 9
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 12GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: HMA851S6DJR6N-XN
          vendor: Hynix
          physical id: 0
          serial: 22691E37
          slot: Bottom - Slot 1 (left)
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: AO1P26KC8T1-BXPS
          vendor: A-DATA Technology
          physical id: 1
          serial: 4FB00000
          slot: Bottom - Slot 2 (right)
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: b
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 192KiB
       capacity: 192KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: c
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: d
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

If you need any more outputs, I will apply edits below. Any help would be wonderful. Thank you, everyone have a nice day!

Comment: Your spinning-disk has a real-world throughput that is equivalent to a USB3.0 pen drive. That will limit the amount of performance one might get from even the most performant of systems. There will be too much back-and-forth to the disk even with your 12GB of single-channel RAM. If you have an M2 slot in the machine, consider getting a flash drive — even if it’s SATA rather than NVMe — if you demand a fast boot time. SATA SSDs are 5x faster than your spinning disk. NVMe are > 12x faster. Tweaking OS configurations *for faster boots* is generally a suboptimal use of time 

Comment: I have seen online and often get the tip to replace my HDD with an SSD. However, I cannot afford to get one at the moment. Perhaps I will have to save up for a SSD or a better HDD. Is there perhaps a way to enable a pseudo shut down (like Windows hibernation?)

Comment: “Pseudo shutdowns” leave a partition in an unclean state. Accessing that partition from another OS can then lead to data loss. “Fast boot” in a multi-boot scenario is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I see. So what would you do in this situation?

Comment: My first computer had a 16MHz 8088 CPU and 20MB of storage on a pair of MFM hard drives. DOS 3.1 booted in about 60 seconds if my memory hasn’t completely failed. I used to — and still do — grab something to drink between the time I start the computer and the time it is ready for me to use. Mind you, my machines generally see a reboot only once a month. I use VMs when jumping between OSes.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `snap list` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I uploaded the outputs. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot suggestions...

**DISK**

As perviously mentioned, a SSD would have a major impact on your boot times. 1TB SSDs are now less than $100.

**RAM**

Because you have unmatched RAM SODIMM/DIMMs, you don't get the speed advantage of memory interleaving. Replacing the 4G RAM with a 8G RAM would improve things.

AMD processors are very fussy about RAM. Suggest running a memory test. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**SWAP**

A 2G /swapfile is too small. We'll increase it to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 12G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the swapfile tip. It reduced the startup time to 1 minute and 57 seconds. Not ready to do SSD because I'm not comfortable taking apart my laptoop myself and can't afford a professional, so I'll just learn to practice patience.

Comment: I am getting an SSD to help with the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @AidanReiss That will be the best investment that you'll make, and you'll be so happy with the boot speed, etc.